# Resistors and dependent voltage sources

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

why not $i(2\;kΩ)=15\;mA$ and $i(5\;kΩ)=4\;mA$?

Comment: Your picture is quite small. Do you have a version with larger fonts? Would be easier to read.

Comment: Your title is misleading. There are no dependent voltage sources in this circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer would be correct if there was no voltage drop across the resistor on the right; but since a voltage will be developed there because of the return currents, the voltage across the resistors is less than the 30 V, 20 V of the respective batteries.

It might be easier to see this is so if you drew the circuit in a slightly different form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your awnser is not correct because in the equation V=RI , V is the potential difference of the resistor but in the question The potential difference of the resistors are not 30 and 20 volts. 30 and 20 volts are the potential difference of the batteries.